# Проблема с циклом for - Java

Tags: java

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int rokPrzestepny = 1960;
            for (int i = 1960; i < 1984; i++) {
            rokPrzestepny += 4;
            System.out.println(rokPrzestepny);
        }
    }
}
```

Почему на выходе я получаю числа:

```
1964
1968
1972
1976
1980
1984
1988
1992
1996
2000
2004
2008
2012
2016
2020
2024
2028
2032
2036
2040
2044
2048
2052
2056
```

если у меня в цикле указано что `i < 1984`, то есть я должен получить:

```
1964
1968
1972
1976
1980
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 4):

Это не проблема, это две разные переменные: в цикле указано `i`, а на печать выводится `rokPrzestepny` ¯\*(ツ)*/¯